# How can I create a keyboard shortcut for a phrase?

Tags: dictionary, keyboard-shortcuts

On Apple iOS, there is a section in the settings where you can assign a letter sequence ("shortcut") to any text you want.  When you type that letter sequence, the text you assigned to it shows up as the default replacement if you enter a space.  Of course, there is another "replacement" available which is the letter sequence itself so that you can still have that letter sequence in your typing.

EXAMPLE:
I assigned mmb to the address of my rented mailbox.  When I type mmb on my iPhone, my rented address is the default and replaces the "mmb" I typed if I tap the space key.  If I want it to say "mmb" then I have to tap the replacement option that has "mmb" in quotes.

In this way, I can send my rented mailbox address to anyone who needs it by typing mmb.  There are several other short letter sequences that I also use on my iPhone.  I'm switching to Android, so I'd really like this functionality on my Android.

I have a Samsung Galaxy 4 running Android 5.01.  Apparently, there is no longer a "personal dictionary."  I installed the "User Dictionary Manager" which allowed me to create a shortcut, but when I'm sending a message, the shortcut is ignored.